# Excel: Trying to find if part of a cell is found in a list of cells

Tags: excel, find, partial

I have a list of different application names:

Example Small List:

- CPS Mainframe Processor
- DD(Distributor Directory)
- Deinstallation Calendar

Then I pull reports weekly from another tool that names these applications differently. For example in the first list DD (Distributor Directory) is the application name, but it can be named Distributor Directory and DD Hub from the other list from the reports I pull.

So I need a function that can tell if both names are the same by testing parts of it since it will never be the exact same name/order.
Has anyone ever had to do this before? Please help.

Comment: multi-conditional `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a crosswalk type of reference table? An alternative would be to do your evaluations via code using a case select, but that would require more effort to make changes or additions and other users who may need to support the changes would need a basic understanding of VBA.

For your reference table, you would export all valid values from your reference systems into a column (or multiples depending upon if you need to index by source system, etc), then have an adjoining column that would show your rolled up value. This could also be stored centrally and referenced by multiple people if you are distributing your work.

Example:

> **Source Value        | Report Value**
>
> Distributor Directory | DD(Distributor Directory)
>
> DD Hub                | DD(Distributor Directory)

You could use basic Match, Index, or Lookup functions in Excel to pull in the report value you specify in the table